# how can I implement java EOF

Tags: java, c++

I'm learning java from the very beginning and I'm trying to accept a problem in a programming site, Its very basic, all i need to do is to print a+b till the end of file, I searched everywhere for EOF and all of them implemented an end of file,supposing a real file, but in the problem I'm writing the code of, I shouldn't use actual file.
I use this code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int a,b;
 while(cin>>a)
  {
   cin>>b;
   cout<<a+b<<endl;
  }
}
```

now I kinda converted it in this way to java:

```
package a.b;
import java.util.*;  

public class AB {  

static Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a,b;
    a=in.nextInt();
    while(in.nextInt()!=null)
    {
        b=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a+b);
        a=in.nextInt();
    }

 }
}
```

but I don't know how to implement an EOF for it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: http://sharecode.ir/section/problemset/problem/1001

Comment: You are ignoring every second number as nextInt() returns the next value which you discard (after checking if it is null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

system default input stream has no eof ... rather you can implement:

it should not be

```
    in.nextInt()!=null
```

but rather

```
     in.hasNextInt()
```

or you may get a line

```
      in.nextLine();
```

and then extract each number separately by your own method.